# How to shut down the system in a qt application using a button click?

Tags: qt4

I just want to know how to shut down the system by clicking a button in a qt window. I am using qt creator 2.0.1.

I tried the code

```
system("/usr/bin/halt -p");
```

but nothing happened.
How can my program shut down the system in a qt application using a button onclick?

Answer (score 1):

Shutting down a system via `/usr/bin/halt` usually requires `root` privileges, and most people should not be running your qt application as `root`.  So, you may not be able to do it.  Alternatively, you may need to launch `sudo root /usr/bin/halt -p` and have the user supply their password to `sudo`.  That is likely fraught with multiple issues, unless there is already library support for such operations (which is conceivable).